# UITableViewCell Data changes after scrolling

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, xcode6

I am creating a form in UITableViewCell, this form has lable and text field, in prototype cell. See its image here
[TableView Story board Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVMPE.png).
I am using identifier to dynamically create the form, my code is

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("protocell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    var lable = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    lable.text = details[indexPath.row]
    lable.textColor = UIColor.brownColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.7)

    var textfield = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UITextField
    textfield.placeholder = "Enter \(details[indexPath.row])"
    self.arrayTextField.append(textfield)
    if details[indexPath.row] == "Name" {
        textfield.placeholder = "Enter First \(details[indexPath.row]) Middle \(details[indexPath.row]) Last \(details[indexPath.row]) "
    }
    textfield.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2)

    return cell
}
```

Now the problem is I am having 18 fields and when I enter values in the field and scroll the the view to fill the remaining fields, the values changes in the fields changes.
Please help.

Comment: You need to keep track in your datasource which textfield has text. So when in `tableView:(tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)` is has one, you put it, else, you put your placeHolder, because cells are reused.

Comment: **Never** use arrays containing UI elements of table view cells (`arrayTextField`). That's probably the reason of your problem. Consider to improve the design of your (data source) model, change the data in the model and reload the table view.

Comment: to keep track of datasource i am using `arrayTextField` @Larme how to track in the datasource to see which textfield has text. I have searched but found nothing.

Comment: An array of text fields is misuse of the model-view-controller pattern. This causes your issues. **Don't do that**. You should track the corresponding property in the model which sets the text of the textfield in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `UITableViewCell` subclass and override `prepeareForReuse` function - to turn cell to default mode.

Swift:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    //set cell to initial state here, reset or set values, etc.
}
```

As per your comment - of how to subclass `UITableViewCell`:

```
import UIKit

class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {
     // things that you can do here:
     // initialise your properties here. (label, textfield. etc)
     // layout subviews.
     // override superclass APIs.
}
```

Comment: I am a beginner in iphone  app development, so can @Evegeny Karkan can you will show me how to create subclass.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not store the textfields in an array instead datasource "details" array should do it.
2. Once you have entered any thing in the textfield update you "details" array for that indexPath.
3. Subclass UITableViewCell and make a **CustomTableViewCell** and have IBOutlets for you textfields labels and what not to make your life easier
4. Have a method on your **CustomTablewViewCell** like `updateWithDetails(details)` so that the code is well encapsulated

Comment: my **details** array, contains labels for the fields, so i can't update it.

Comment: so then remove those from the array . Your details array should contain some object like EmployeesDetails * employeeDetails and then array should be then employeDetailsArray. And then for each EmployeeDetails can have the "information" as String rather then textfield. Your dataSource should not contain any UI elements keep those separate.

Comment: my details array is like `details = ["name","address", contactnumber",]` and so on.